# Utilizando JExcel para leitura e escrita

Tags: java

Estou fazendo uma algoritmo simples, para ler uma planilha excel, inserir alguns registros e salvar a planilha alterada.

Para escrever o meu código, tomei como base o exemplo de escrita disponibilizado junto ao pacote do JExcel, dessa forma tenho um método que é responsável por ler a planilha, aplicar o conteúdo, escrever esse conteúdo na planilha e salvá-la.

```cs
    public void gerarPlanilhaPreenchida(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException{

    File inputTemplate = new File(inputFile);
    File outputTemplate = new File(outputFile);

    Workbook planilhaTemplate;
    WritableWorkbook planilhaResultado;

    try{

        planilhaTemplate = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputTemplate);
        planilhaResultado = Workbook.createWorkbook(outputTemplate, planilhaTemplate);

        aplicaConteudo(planilhaResultado);

        planilhaResultado.write();
        planilhaResultado.close();

    }
    catch(BiffException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Segue o código do método responsável por produzir o conteúdo a ser escrito, comecei simples, inserindo novas linhas na planilha:

```cs
    private void aplicaConteudo(WritableWorkbook w) throws WriteException {

    WritableSheet excelSheet = w.getSheet("INSS");
    excelSheet.insertRow(11);

}
```

Para testar:

```cs
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RowsExceededException, WriteException, IOException {

    String inputFile = "<<HOME_FOLDER>>/entrada/PlanilhaTemplate.xls";
    String outputFile = "<HOME_FOLDER<>>/saida/PlanilhaTemplate2.xls";

    GenerateExcelLogic novaPlanilhaTeste = new GenerateExcelLogic();
        novaPlanilhaTeste.gerarPlanilhaPreenchida(inputFile, outputFile);
}
```

Esse é o log de erro ao executar o `main`:

> Warning:  cannot insert row within formula:  Unrecognized token 61
>   Warning:  cannot insert row within formula:  Unrecognized token 60
>   Warning:  cannot insert row within formula:  Unrecognized token 60
>   Warning:  cannot insert row within formula:  Unrecognized token 60
>   Warning:  cannot insert row within formula:  Unrecognized token 60
>   Warning:  cannot insert row within formula:  Unrecognized token 60
>   Warning:  cannot insert row within formula:  Unrecognized token 60
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at jxl.biff.formula.TokenFormulaParser.getBytes(TokenFormulaParser.java:495)
>     at jxl.biff.formula.FormulaParser.getBytes(FormulaParser.java:183)
>     at
>   jxl.write.biff.ReadFormulaRecord.getData(ReadFormulaRecord.java:145)
>     at jxl.biff.WritableRecordData.getBytes(WritableRecordData.java:71)
>     at jxl.write.biff.File.write(File.java:147)
>     at jxl.write.biff.RowRecord.writeCells(RowRecord.java:342)
>     at jxl.write.biff.SheetWriter.write(SheetWriter.java:480)
>     at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.write(WritableSheetImpl.java:1558)
>     at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.write(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:950)
>     at br.com.madi.projeto.GenerateExcelLogic.gerarPlanilhaInss(GenerateExcelLogic.java:45)
>     at br.com.madi.projeto.GenerateExcelLogic.main(GenerateExcelLogic.java:68)

OBS: A minha planilha Excel funciona como um *Template*, é apenas necessário inserir os dados. Neste caso, quando no `insertRow()` peço para ele inserir uma linha dentro do meu *Template*, recebo o erro acima, agora quando a linha está fora do *Template*, não recebo o erro. Porém não consigo ter certeza se a planilha foi alterada ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é causado porque a biblioteca JExcel não conseguiu avaliar uma fórmula na sua planilha de template. A fórmula deve ter um *range* do qual uma ou mais células daquela linha fazem parte e, ao tentar atualizar a fórmula para incluir mais linhas ela não consegue. Este é o motivo pelo qual numa planilha nova o código funciona.

Verifique se a fórmula está correta e se a biblioteca JExcel suporta aquela as funções e a sintaxe utilizadas. Uma possibilidade é que algum recurso das versões mais novas do Excel esteja sendo usado e a biblioteca não esteja atualizada.

Enfim, procure a fórmula com problemas e, se precisar de mais ajuda, atualize a pergunta com a fórmula que causa o erro.

Comment: Olá, imaginei que fosse, porém retirei todas as formulas do template para evitar problema. Vou continuar verificando, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Cara, fiz a alterações, e tive sucesso, vou tirar todas as formulas do template, e aplicar via JExcel. Obrigado.

Comment: @VictorFelipe Ótima ideia. Que bom que conseguiu resolver. :)